# WaitForMultipleObjects doesn't signal for stdin in Wine

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wine

I wanted to be signaled when stdin has something. Below code works as expected in windows 11.

In windows 11 whatever key you press signals it but in Wine it doesn't matter what key you press nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>

#ifndef STDIN_FILENO
    #define STDIN_FILENO 0
#endif

int main(){
    HANDLE handles[1];
    handles[0] = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(STDIN_FILENO);
    while(1){
        DWORD r = WaitForMultipleObjects(1, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if(r != WAIT_OBJECT_0){
            printf("error WaitForMultipleObjects %d\n", r);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("stdin is triggered\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why Wine acts different than windows 11? Is something wrong in code?

Comment: Does it wake up if ENTER is pressed?

Comment: It doesn't wake up

Comment: Does it make a difference if you call `fflush( stdout );` after every `printf` statement? (You have to insert that line in two places in order to test that.)

Comment: I tried and nothing changed also every printf has return after it so flushing stdout must be not a problem

Comment: If you replace `(HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(STDIN_FILENO);` with `GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );`, is the behavior the same?

Comment: Behavior is same.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Wine, then. BTW, why are you using `WaitForMultipleObjects()` instead of `WaitForSingleObject()`?

Comment: WaitFor*Objects loop needs to be in other thread since I don't want to make it lock my main thread. And it needs to report what is triggered to main thread in async way. Multiple object waitting is profit because you can also make it wait for `SetEvent` which can be used for add/remove/change other objects from main thread with mutexes.

Comment: *Why Wine acts different than windows 11?* may be because wine not windows